# Tree deactivation in AEM (deactivate all child nodes when root node is deactivated)

Tags: aem

I have a requirement in which I have to do a tree deactivation to the pages which have been tree activated earlier. Is there a way in AEM already to do this? We are using AEM6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default de-activation happens in similar way as tree activation, like it handles the tree below it. When you deactivate `root-page`, it would deactivate all the nodes below it, in following case all children (`child-page1, child-page2, child-of-page2`) and `root-page`.

```
/content/myapp/root-page
--- child-page1
--- child-page2
---------- child-of-page2
```

Select the path you want deactivate, use "Deactivate" button, it would deactivate all nodes under that path. There is no specific functionality provided by AEM for tree de-activation.

Answer (score 0):

When you deactivate any page all the pages under it will automatically get de activated.